# How the build flutter gradle? Its failed

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, gradle, flutter-dependencies

I added the firestore and firebase auth to my flutter project, but now it is not starting.

If I write `gradlew build` in the terminal I get a error code:

```
> Configure project :app
Adding a Configuration as a dependency is a confusing behavior which isn't recommended. This behaviour has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 8.0. If you're interested in inheriting the dependencies from the Configuration you are adding, you s
hould use Configuration#extendsFrom instead. See https://docs.gradle.org/6.7/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.Configuration.html#org.gradle.api.artifacts.Configuration:extendsFrom(org.gradle.api.artifacts.Configuration[]) for more details.
        at build_90hb1guh6a6ptpmu6otfn4x4q$_run_closure3.doCall(D:\eyyup\AndroidStudioProjects\todo\android\build.gradle:27)
        (Run with --stacktrace to get the full stack trace of this deprecation warning.)
The AbstractArchiveTask.destinationDir property has been deprecated. This is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 7.0. Please use the destinationDirectory property instead. See https://docs.gradle.org/6.7/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.AbstractArchiveTask.html#org.
gradle.api.tasks.bundling.AbstractArchiveTask:destinationDir for more details.
        at FlutterPlugin$_addFlutterTasks_closure16$_closure35.doCall(D:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle:762)
        (Run with --stacktrace to get the full stack trace of this deprecation warning.)
The AbstractArchiveTask.archiveName property has been deprecated. This is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 7.0. Please use the archiveFileName property instead. See https://docs.gradle.org/6.7/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.AbstractArchiveTask.html#org.gradle.a
pi.tasks.bundling.AbstractArchiveTask:archiveName for more details.
        at FlutterPlugin$_addFlutterTasks_closure16$_closure35.doCall(D:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle:763)
        (Run with --stacktrace to get the full stack trace of this deprecation warning.)

> Configure project :firebase_auth
WARNING: The option setting 'android.enableR8=true' is deprecated.
It will be removed in version 5.0 of the Android Gradle plugin.
You will no longer be able to disable R8

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:lintVitalRelease'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':app:debugAndroidTestCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:.
     Required by:
         project :app

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5s
```

What can I do the solve this problem?

Comment: did upu add google-service.json file in android app level

Comment: show your android level and app level build gradle file

Answer (score 0):

Did you remember to update your build.gradle files? Or did you create this project with an older version of Flutter (in which case the dependencies might be too old for that version of Firebase Analytics).

Check that your android/build.gradle file contains the following:

```
 buildscript {
     ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
     repositories {
         google()
         jcenter()
     }
 
     dependencies {
         classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
         classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
         classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
     }
 }
```

and your android/app/build.gradle file contains the following:

```
dependencies {
    def multidex_version = "2.0.1"
    implementation "androidx.multidex:multidex:$multidex_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.2'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Further information is here https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/2649#issuecomment-635855829

Comment: I have now add >apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'< under dependencies but it is not working

Comment: You deleted the comment containing your build.gradle so I'm not 100% sure, but from the error message, you might need to check that your android/build.gradle file contains the google() maven repository:

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
(https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/blob/c3b13af41e2fadc22a44ebbcd14a8ac4736d9e75/packages/firebase_analytics/firebase_analytics/example/android/build.gradle#L16). Then run flutter upgrade/flutter clean/flutter packages get and try again.